# Curl: What Url could cause "CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT"?

Tags: curl

For testing purpose, I need to feed curl with a wrong URL to trigger a "CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT" error. But no matter how I try, I couldn't make it happen. The most error I get is cannot resolve host, or unsupported protocol etc. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching the curl sources leads to... [multiple tests](https://github.com/bagder/curl/search?q=CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT&ref=cmdform) that are supposed to trigger this same error. For example,

```
pop3://host:port/%0d%0a/1322
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I check the source code and it seems "port out of range" is a pretty good one.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

> curl ???

It throws:

> curl: (3)  malformed

Comment: Interesting, mine returned 6. $ curl --version
curl 7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP 
$ curl ???
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'doc'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'mip'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'vpn'

Comment: I don't know if this will be any help, but here:
$ curl --version
curl 7.27.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.27.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1c zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: Debug GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP